# Should I post an answer if it adds value to the question, but doesn't answer it directly?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question

For a matter of fact, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42311276/converting-milliseconds-to-amount-of-time-string) question asks how to convert millis to other amounts of time using PhP.

But, I know that Bukkit (one of the question tags, useful tag) uses Java as it's main language.

I believe that future users that might come into the question might want to know how to do it using the bukkit platform.

Should I create an answer adding the Java solution besides the PhP solution, or should I just expect future users to ask their own question if they want the Java solution?

Would the answer be off-topic?

Comment: There is no reason this question has to be tagged with [tag:bukkit] in the first place. It is not hinted at anywhere in the question. (and I've removed it from the question).