# How should I share code+ideas that can help someone get closer to finding an answer but doesn't entirely answer their question?

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer

I came across a question that is rather technical and for which I do not have an answer. At the same time, I do not expect others to provide them with an answer in a reasonable amount of time since it is so specialized. Nevertheless, I have code (same language, software, etc.) that could get them maybe 75% of the way to an answer and some thoughts on how they might approach the problem to get all the way to an answer.

What is the appropriate way to communicate this information to help them?

Looked around meta but didn't see anything exactly like this. Most related were:

[Should an answer that discusses a general concept but doesn't address the problem be considered NAA?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276759/should-an-answer-that-discusses-a-general-concept-but-doesnt-address-the-proble)

[Should I post an answer if it adds value to the question, but doesn't answer it directly?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344175/should-i-post-an-answer-if-it-adds-value-to-the-question-but-doesnt-answer-it)

[Answering questions with no "proper" technical solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290684/answering-questions-with-no-proper-technical-solution)

Comment: If the question requires so much work to answer completely, and you feel there is a well-defined point where they are 75% there – are you sure it's not more appropriate for the question to focus on a smaller problem? Say, 75% of what they have now?

Comment: I'd assume [this is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73092453/2821954) and you [got an error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73120516/2821954) when trying to solve it?

Comment: For Andrew - Different question, but that's a different case I wasn't really considering that perhaps would be applicable as well.

For MisterMiyagi - Not really that it requires so much work, but moreso that it's niche and technical and I myself don't know the full answer with certainty either. But that's a good way of thinking about it.

Comment: "... which I do not have an answer." You say you have 75% of the answer as you say. Depending on how essential the remaining 25% are, this might be a significant amount and worth putting into an answer.

Comment: It's worth pointing out, that the general view is that homework questions should be answered deliberately only in part, I.e. helping the user on the right path, without doing their work for them, and these are clearly not considered NAA. Moreover answers (and questions for that matter) that concentrate on the principles rather than get bogged down in detail are likely to benefit a wider audience. So I say go for it.

Comment: When I encounter such questions and have not the full answer, but I think that it could be useful, I sometimes answer as a community wiki. Just be sure that the answer is also valuable, and not just an addendum to further specify the question. It should also not ask for clarification etc. This also potentially encourages other users (more than with non-community-wikis) to edit the answer and expand it further.

Comment: @Lino Please don't.

Comment: @IanKemp Why not?

Comment: @IanKemp yeah, why not? If the anwer is broad enough to cover similar questions and problems, but specific enough to help the OP I don't see a reason not to post it. I have to admit though that it is kind of a loophole as it's not an NAA to warrant deletion, but one also doesn't suffer from repurcussions when the answer is badly received.

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter `x` re a comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. But without `@` others get no notification.

Comment: To some extent, it will depend on *why* the 75% answer isn't a 100% answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think our [advice for answering homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/211627) is applicable, even if the OP did not specifically indicate that it's a question about schoolwork. Technically, [we do not distinguish between homework and non-homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404053/211627) when answering or evaluating quality, so the advice found in the FAQ is all the more relevant since it applies to all answers, not just answers to homework questions.

Specifically the following:

> - **Try to provide an explanation** that will *lead the asker in the correct direction*. Genuine understanding is the real goal for students, but trying to provide that is usually appreciated for *any* question.

If your answer is relevant and provides a foundation for understanding the nature of the problem, then whether or not you have a relevant snippet of code is immaterial.

The second point is also relevant:

> - **It's usually better *not to provide a complete code sample*** if you believe it would not help the student, using your best judgment. You can use pseudo-code first, and, in the spirit of creating a programming resource, you may come back after a suitable amount of time and edit your response to include more complete code. This way, the student still has to write their own code, but a full solution can become available after the assignment has ended.

There is no requirement in any of our documentation to use code in an answer. It's usually very helpful to do so, but you don't have to. As noted in the help documentation, [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):

> *Any answer that fully addresses **at least part of** the question is helpful and can **get the asker going in the right direction**. State any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.* (emphasis mine)

Sounds like this is exactly what you are doing, so your answer would be welcome.

As stated at the end of the last quote, it's ok to note that you don't have a complete solution, or that you don't have a solution in their preferred language, etc. However, I'd recommend that you either use pseudo-code or else carefully explain what your code is doing if it's not in the OP's requested language. Don't assume that they or future readers will understand it.

Comment: This is a nice summary of several of the other points made in other answers and hits on what I think are the main ideas found **in SO official resources**

Comment: (It's probably worth adding that even if you do everything "right" you'll probably still get the occasional downvote. You can't make everyone happy all the time.)

Answer (score 26):

I think as long as you are attempting to answer their question and have some valuable information, that's far better than receiving no answers, and will often solve the problem anyway.

If you think about some very basic question, 75% and some comments is a great answer; it points them in the right direction but still gives some room to learn. On the other hand, a very deep question might have an issue with the first 25% and after getting over that initial jump, they can complete the question.

The [Answering Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) say:

> So long as you **fully answer at least a part of the original question**, then you can contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried.

> Any answer that **fully addresses at least part of the question** is helpful and can get the asker going in the right direction. State any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.

So if you have a partial answer paired with additional comments and which address the question, I think you fulfill both. It is important to be clear that your answer is meant to get them going in the right direction, and will require some further thought. Don't try to pass it off as a drop-in solution.

Comment: I think this answer can be accepted provided that it provides support for this claim, which I think is found in this page @ack provided https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer The key is that "valuable" has a bit of a specific definition here: the answer must fully answer at least part of the original question. If you can incorporate the policies laid out in that page into your answer then I think this most accurately provides "the SO doctrine" on it.

Comment: This answer is misleading. The answering guidelines establish "fully answer [...] part of the [...] question". It's not that you would only partially answer the question, but you will take an issue that the question presents and answering it fully.

Answer (score 12):

Just answer the question to the best of your abilities, but there is something I wanted to point out.

> ... At the same time, I do not expect others to provide them with an answer in a reasonable amount of time since it is so specialized.

We have no time quota to meet to deliver answers to others.  This is a form of asynchronous communication and as such, we cannot and should not try to respond to requests in near real-time.

Comment: Yes, but the OP is I think trying to make a distinction between "easy" questions that someone else will probably come along and fully answer (or close as duplicate), vs. harder interesting questions where it's worth collaborating towards a solution by sharing what you know.  Lowering the barrier for others (including the OP) to work out a complete answer if they're interested.  That's not worth doing if you expect many other SO users already know what you know about the problem, especially if it's an easy problem (like the kind that people run into when learning a new language.)

Answer (score 6):

If it's a subject area where you have some expertise, and it's *still* a tricky question for you to fully answer, then it's probably tricky for other people as well.  It's helpful to post as much of an answer as you can (or have time to write), if that can hopefully give future readers something to build on, and/or a pointer right direction.

**Make it clear that it's *not* a complete answer.**  If a reader knows that up front, they can read it with an eye towards building on it.  Rather than wondering if they missed something when reading / skimming your answer, if they were expecting (hoping) to find an answer to the complete problem.

---

**If you don't have much experience yourself with the language or subject matter, usually don't post half-answers.**  Someone who does know the language or problem-domain probably can post a complete answer fairly easily, and a confused beginner answer is likely to just be clutter.  Or worse, misleading if your partial solution is a step down a wrong (or over-complicated) path.

I know this isn't the case you talked about in the question, but some commenters have raised objections to partial answers.  Those objections are warranted in other cases, where a complete answer isn't hard for experts; Stack Overflow doesn't need everyone's beginner attempt at a problem, or a blog post about their attempts to learn a new language.

---

It's a judgement call on whether you think other people probably know the answer and are willing / able to write and post one.  In this case, you say it's a problem related to one you looked at, so your assessment is likely correct.

Answer (score -3):

Code and ideas that can help someone get closer to finding an answer are appropriate for a forum. Stack Overflow is not a forum.

This was a deliberate choice made by its creators to overcome one of the inherent problems with forums, namely their informality - which generates a large amount of off-topic and unhelpful posts relative to actual solutions, and as such finding those solutions becomes extremely difficult. The answer is a more formal setting, hence Stack Overflow.

That means there's nowhere appropriate to post the help you're suggesting on Stack Overflow. The best you can do is start a chat with the user in question or direct them to an external forum where you can help them, but that is often infeasible because that asker is long gone. That is an unfortunate but inherent issue with the way this site is intended to work.

In short, posting half-answers and breadcrumbs is against the very intentions of this site. Don't do it, because your efforts will be wasted as your posts are removed for failing to conform to the rules.

Comment: Except that SE is a forum. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/forum It may not be the typical online forum like FB or Reddit, but it's still a type of forum. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92122/671964 Even a partial answer is better than nothing. I've been awarded bounties for simply pointing an asker in the right direction, even though I didn't have the "perfect answer". Too many people want perfect answers, and when they don't get one, they downvote it, even though it's relevant. Posting half answers is the very point of this site in that we often don't know the 100% answer.

Comment: @computercarguy you are welcome to your opinion as to what you want Stack Overflow to be. That does not change what it **is**, nor does it change the rules that were built around that reality. That you were awarded bounties for not-answers does not change that either. People downvoting your not-answers are likely doing so precisely because they're not-answers. And posting half-answers is very much NOT the point of this site, as I've already explained in my answer.

Comment: The very problematic idea that SE not being a forum and that people don't like partial answers is that people very much do like and up vote partial answers. If that weren't the case, all answers except the accepted one would be deleted, but multiple partial answers do get people to a full answer. In fact, it's pretty common for people to post partial answers to what part they can answer, and answers to not repeat what's covered elsewhere. The **fact** is that SE *is* a forum, and it's *your* opinion that it isn't. The rules simply prevent it from being a social media type of forum.

Comment: Whether SE is a forum or not is semantics. The goal of SE is about learning. Further, if "respondents weigh in with a carefully thought-out response which is then vetted through voting and wiki-editing (improving on the answer)." then this combats the informal and half-baked answers. Both of these points leads me to believe that a well thought-out 75% of the answered question answer belongs on the site.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer: "_So long as you **fully answer at least a part of the original question**, then you can contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried. That way, **even if you can’t figure it out, the next person has more to go on**. _"

Comment: I think this last comment is a pretty decisive case for posting answers in this case.

Comment: @computercarguy -- _"The fact is that SE is a forum, and it's your opinion that it isn't."_ Well, the general consensus around here has been that SO is _not_ a forum, and [certainly not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294774/is-stack-overflow-not-a-forum). Since one of the most commonly accepted definitions for forum is a place for open discussion, I don't understand why you insist on banging on this drum. I also don't see how this has any bearing on whether partial answers are acceptable. Partial answers have always been welcome, so long at they are substantial.

Comment: The very first thing you read on the [tour] is _"Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.... we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming."_ I don't agree with @IanKemp that this means that partial answers are not allowed, but I could see how you might come to this interpretation. This description doesn't fit any type of internet forum I have participated in; I think that the creators of SO had something more disciplined in mind, i.e, a repository of self-contained Q&As.

Comment: @adabsurdum, if this set of sites isn't a discussion forum, then why are there so many discussions on all of them? We are literally having a discussion right now. I don't get how people want to shut the door to discussion when it's the only way that a Q&A site works. You *have* to discuss the problem and how the answer fits. Especially when the asker doesn't understand what's answered. If discussions weren't allowed, there would be no room for comments. Heck, there's discussions all the time on if questions are fit for the sites.

Comment: @computercarguy People might (ab)use comments for discussion but that's [not their intended function](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). The core Q&A is not a discussion in itself and is definitely *not* a debate – there is *one* question with no back-and-forth between several answers and question*s*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, you must have a very different experience than I do with SE/SO sites. I see a lot of questions in answers getting answered in the question so the answer can be written better and fit the actual situation better. I've seen comments on answers prompt the OP to update the question to make it better, more clear. That's clearly a discussion, by definition. I also see answers debate whether the question is the right one to ask with "frame challenge" answers, and there are answers that conflict with other answers, while debating whether those other answers are correct.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, also, I find that the comments are there specifically for discussion, which the article you linked only limits "secondary discussion", which implies there's a primary discussion, so there's an actual discussion happening as outlined in the rest of that article.

Comment: @computercarguy -- Questions and answers are privileged content on SO, but comments are ephemeral. A Q&A has a question and an answer, but no back-and-forth. Comments are a type of back-and-forth discussion intended for clarification and criticism of questions and answers; ideally these comments lead to improvement of the real content. From the perspective of SO, all comments could be deleted today and nothing substantial about the site would change, leaving only the Q&A with no back-and-forth. If you removed all of the back-and-forth from an internet forum you would have an empty forum.

Comment: @adabsurdum, so because discussion can be removed it means that there's no discussions at all, which means that it's not a forum? Talk about a circular argument. Not to mention that the vast amount of comments that are discussions aren't removed. And while you admit that there are discussions happening, you still insist that this isn't a forum? That sounds as if you are trying to sell a contradiction so that you can be correct, even when it's demonstrable that you aren't. If anyone is obstinate about their opinion, it seems to be you, not me. My position isn't an opinion, it's based in fact.

Comment: @computercarguy -- No. The content that is actively fostered on SO is question and answer content, not comments and discussion. I don't know how you have shifted to the idea that discussion equals forum, but the discussion part is irrelevant to what makes SO valuable. If you remove discussion from an _actual_ forum, there is nothing left.

Comment: Seems to me that some people use "forum" to mean *any* forum, while others use it to mean specifically a *discussion* forum.  Let's stop debating the definition of words and focus on the actual topic of the question.

Comment: @Slate "The goal of SE is about learning" [citation needed] the /tour says "we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming". The fact that you can learn from that is not that it's the goal. I don't read SO answers to learn, I read them to solve a problem I have. Heck, I've edited/downvoted questions merely because it states something that I want to solve but then it devolves into something else that I have no interest in.

Comment: @Braiam, so you come here to learn how to solve a problem, but not to learn? That makes no sense. And downvoting because you aren't interested in it is not how voting is supposed to work. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: @RyanM, I'd like for people to stop trying to redefine words into something only a single meaning and losing most the scope of what the word means when they apparently don't like the other meanings.

Comment: **Stack Overflow in a nutshell:** User posts "_SO is not a forum_". Immediately triggers a long comment thread about the definition of "forum".

Comment: @computercarguy no, since I have more important information to store in my memory, like knowing that SO has the answer to those problems. I don't need to memorize everything I read, just know how to search for it.

Comment: @JDB, well, SE has a huge amount of documentation saying we need to post factual answers, so when someone posts an inaccurate answer, it tends to comments that try to correct it. Are we not supposed to do that anymore? Or are factual answers just forbidden for topics that SE holds sacrosanct? A rose by any other name is still a forum.

Comment: @computercarguy In short, we are a motley crew of egotistical pedants who won't shrink from the opportunity to bicker about the most absurd things, but it often goes with the personality types drawn to "_software engineer_".  Sometimes it helps to chuckle and move on with your life. No one will die if we are unable to nail down the definition of "forum" or what, _EXACTLY_, is the purpose of a site used by over ~14~ [18 million](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#users) people.

Comment: @JDB, I wish that sentiment was used for more than definitions (especially when definitions of words are pretty important to any kind of communication), like when someone makes a typo, but the post is still easily understandable. Or when someone uses a different type of loop than their preferred type. Or at least a dozen other reasons why I see people VTC, DV, or make scathing comments. I've raised concerns about that, too, and I get the same kind of response as I've gotten here: it's sacrosanct that everything needs to be shredded if it can be.

Comment: Isn't it interesting that the people liking that kind of attitude don't like it applied to them?

Comment: @computercarguy - In a community of roughly 18 million, there is never going to be one voice that speaks for all. Arguing with a half-dozen folks in a comment thread on Meta isn't really going to move the needle. Definitions are important but, with such a large community, we always have to settle for something less than precise. I empathize with you, it's uncomfortable, but it's reality. Thinking of it as one versus 17.99999 million people probably isn't helpful. [Now go vote however you want to.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251487/getting-to-know-stack-overflows-voting-culture)

Comment: @JDB, I don't see it as 18 million to 1, I see it as a few dozen who insist SE isn't a forum trying to impose the opinion of 1 on +7 billion. It would also be nice if there was consistency in applying the rules, where people don't have to read half of Meta in order to post. Yes, I've had and seen questions closed for reasons in Meta, not the actual Tour, Help Center, or other official docs.

Comment: @computercarguy - My last comment... don't stress out about it. It takes [3 votes to close a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391832/211627). If you feel you have been unfairly targeted, then post on Meta. It only takes 3 similarly-minded users to reopen it. The original three can't vote a second time. If the community generally likes it, it'll stay open. If the community generally doesn't care or doesn't like it, it'll stay closed. If the community generally dislikes your post, then they dislike it. You aren't a bad person, you just made something most users don't like. Oh well. ‍♂️

Comment: @JDB, you are describing the unwanted "Meta Effect" in the link you previously posted. And this isn't necessarily about me. I've seen a question closed in less than 6 minutes for a not 100% perfect JSON copy & paste error, where the OP fixed a couple of minutes after it was closed and then took 3 days to reopen.